# Elasticsearch и поиск по сайту

Tags: elasticsearch

В качестве способов применения Elastic Stack встретил пример поиска по сайту, где говорится, что Elasticsearch может служить поисковой системой сайта, выполнять поиск как в Google по всему контенту (в частности читал, что Github использует Elasticsearch для реализации поиска).

Мне было не совсем понятно, как данные сайта попадают в Elasticsearch и как туда же попадают обновленные данные в случае, например, обновления статьи, добавления комментариев и тд.

Итак, допустим, на сайте была добавлена статья. Она сохраняется в БД, например, Postgresql. Вопрос: как статья попадает в Elasticsearch? Отправляется "руками" по API?

Comment: «Отправляется "руками" по API?» — да